# How to show MessageBox at a specific point on the screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How can I use `MessageBox.Show("test")` and have it appear at a specific location on the screen. By default, the message box is shown centered on the screen.

Comment: does not work , messagebox does not property top or left

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I position .net's (Forms) Message box or Common dialogs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230299/can-i-position-nets-forms-message-box-or-common-dialogs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. Write your own dialog form.
2. Intercept the Windows messages directed to the dialog and set the position when the dialog is first shown.

The latter of these is probably easiest done by avoiding `MessageBox` altogether and P/Invoking to the native message dialog API.

That said, I can't imagine why you'd want to avoid using the system default behaviour.

Comment: ">I can't imagine why you'd want to avoid using the system default behaviour." **Multi monitor. It's ridiculous for the modal message box for an application on Monitor 4 to show up on Monitor 1.

Comment: @BrianB But surely that's a programming mistake

Answer (score -2):

Syntax in C#:

```
MessageBox.top= 100;
MessageBox.left= 200;
```

Comment: MessageBox only Property have::show & Equals & ReferenceEquals

Comment: which language are you using rite now?

Comment: Freak: Can you point me to the documentation which shows `MessageBox` having `top` and `left` property?